# What is the expected value of the number of heart cards given that I roll a 3?

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose I roll a die and then draw that many cards from a deck
without replacement. What is the expected value of the number
of heart cards given that I roll a 3?

---

So I had this idea of doing:

- X=number obtained on the die
- Y=number of hearts

$E(Y|X=3)= \sum_{y=1}^{3}yP_{(y|x)}(Y|X=3)=6$

Since from my understanding 
$$
P_{(y|x)}(Y|X=3)=\frac{P(y\bigcap x=3)}{P(x=3)}=\frac{P( x=3)}{P(x=3)}=1$$

I have no way to check that if anyone spots an error or would like to find me a better way of doing it that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't know how I could have 6 hearts since I rolled a 3. I was thinking about a number between 1 and 3 but not 6.

Comment: Or maybe I should've used Bayes rule at the denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Given that you are drawing $3$ cards,

- Probability of getting no heart is $\frac{39 \cdot 38 \cdot 37}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50}$
- Probability of getting a heart is $3 \cdot \frac{39 \cdot 38\cdot 13}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50} $
- Probability of getting $3$ hearts is $\frac{13\cdot 12 \cdot 11}{52\cdot 51 \cdot50}$

Can you compute the expected value given these info?

Comment: I'll just need to do 0(prob of getting zero heart)+1(prob of getting 1 heart)+2(prob of getting 2 heart)+3(prob of getting 3 heart)

Comment: yup, just have to compute that quantity.

Comment: Was it that simple? It seems to me now that writing a pmf correctly can get you out of any situations.